# Using the usual notation for a triangle write $\sin^2A$ in terms of the sides a, b and c.

Tags: trigonometry

This is an A-level trigonometric problem.

Using the usual notation for a triangle write $\sin^2A$ in terms of the sides $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer: $$\frac{(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)}{4b^2c^2}$$

The last step of the solution requires going from:

Expression 1: $$-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2$$

to:

Expression 2: $$(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)$$

I can see that these two expressions are equal by working in reverse and multiplying out the second expression to get the first but how does one go from Exp.1 to Exp.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it in a simpler way: start from *Al Kashi's formula*:
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A,$$
 from which you deduce first $4b^2c^2\cos^2A= (b^2+c^2-a^2)^2$, and finally 
\begin{align*}
4b^2c^2\sin^2A&=4b^2c^2- (b^2+c^2-a^2)^2\\
&=(2bc -b^2-c^2+a^2)(2bc +b^2+c^2-a^2)\\
&=[a^2-(b-c)^2][(b+c)^2-a^2]\\
&=[(a-b+c)(a+b-c)][(b+c-a)(b+c+a)].
\end{align*}

Comment: Perfect, and I never realised the cosine rule was called the Al Kashi formula.

Answer (score 1):

$4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2)^2+2(a^2+b^2)c^2-c^4=(2ab)^2-((a^2+b^2)^2-2(a^2+b^2)c^2+c^4))=(2ab)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2$

now you go to last step.

Comment: @mathlove, ya, a mistake of sign. correct it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}&-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2\\&=-a^4+(2b^2+2c^2)a^2-b^4+2b^2c^2-c^4\\&=-a^4+2(b^2+c^2)a^2-(b^2-c^2)^2\\&=\color{red}{-a^4+2(b^2+c^2)a^2-(b^2+c^2)^2}+(b^2+c^2)^2-(b^2-c^2)^2\\&=\color{red}{-(a^2-(b^2+c^2))^2}+4b^2c^2\\&=(2bc)^2-(a^2-b^2-c^2)^2\end{align}$$

Now use $A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)$.

Answer (score 0):

$a+b-c=2(s-c)$ etc.

$$\implies\dfrac{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b+c)}{b^2c^2}=\dfrac{16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{(bc)^2}$$

Now use $\triangle=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=\dfrac12bc\sin A$